# Who is Petrick from Petrick's method?

Tags: boolean-algebra, decimal-expansion

I would like to ask your help. I think this is the best place for this. 
In my language -as well as English- I haven't found anything about Petrick yet. His method okay, but I would like to know about himself, biography like full name, date of/place of birth etc...

I would appreciate if You could help me. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Never heard of him, or her. Some context, please? Where did you come across the name? and is it Petrick, as in the title of your question, or Petick, as in the body? (and can you please edit for consistency?).

Comment: @GerryMyerson: The first answer of the obvious Google search: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petrick's_method

Comment: OK, @Alex, so now the question is whether there's any information about Petrick at any of the links in the Wikipedia essay.

Comment: I've just found a research from him. Monogram could be the "S" and the "R". But it still nothing. 
 Petrick, S. R. (1956). A Direct Determination of the Irredundant Forms of
a Boolean Function from the Set of Prime Implicants. Technical Report
AFCRC-TR-56-110, Air Force Cambridge Research Center, Cambridge,
MA, USA

Comment: Sadly he is not me :(

Answer (score 4):

[image]

I have found it! Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: Good! But – where did you find it?

Answer (score 1):

Petrick's method originates from the 1956 paper "A Direct Determination of the Irredundant Forms of a Boolean Function from the Set of Prime Implicants" written by S. R. Petrick. It was published as a technical report at the US Air Force Cambridge Research Center. Searching for the same name and institution yields more papers by the same author, but very little information about who S. R. Petrick is or was. Some sources also have a citation to a PhD thesis from MIT by S. R. Petrick entitled "A Recognition Procedure for Transformational Grammars", which was published in 1965.